# goJS lock nodes

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have simple python flask app where I send JSON data to my HTML and with goJS I display my graph which looks like this:

[image]

Users can add new nodes and links, but what I want is that starting graph is locked so that users can not edit or delete any nodes or links from that starting graph. I just want that they can add new nodes and links and link it to starting graph nodes.

I really tried to search for this specific case but I haven't found what I am looking for. In [documentation](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/permissions.html) there are some options like disabling whole diagram or set it to read only, but that is not what I need. There are some mentions that you can make specific user permissions, but there is not any examples provided, so I need help.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>State Chart</title>
<meta name="description" content="A finite state machine chart with editable and interactive features." />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.7.27/go.js"></script>
<script src="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/TextEditorRadioButtons.js"></script>
<script src="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/TextEditorSelectBox.js"></script>
<script src="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/DataInspector.js"></script>
<link href="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/DataInspector.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script id="code">

    function init() {

        var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
        myDiagram =
        $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
            // start everything in the middle of the viewport
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            // have mouse wheel events zoom in and out instead of scroll up and down
            "toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior": go.ToolManager.WheelZoom,
            // support double-click in background creating a new node
            "clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData": { text: "new node" },
            // enable undo & redo
            "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
            "layout": new go.ForceDirectedLayout()
        });


        // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function(e) {
            var button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
            if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
            var idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
            if (myDiagram.isModified) {
            if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
            } else {
            if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);
            }
        });

            // define the Node template
        myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
          $(go.Node, "Auto",
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the TextBlock
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
              {
                parameter1: 20,  // the corner has a large radius
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 201, 0)", 1: "rgb(254, 162, 0)" }),
                stroke: null,
                portId: "",  // this Shape is the Node's port, not the whole Node
                fromLinkable: true, fromLinkableDuplicates: true,
                toLinkable: true, toLinkableDuplicates: true,
                cursor: "pointer"
              }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              {
                font: "bold 11pt helvetica, bold arial, sans-serif",
                editable: true  // editing the text automatically updates the model data
                //textEditor: window.TextEditorRadioButtons, // defined in textEditorRadioButtons.js
                // this specific TextBlock has its own choices:
                //choices: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
              },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        );

        myDiagram.nodeTemplate.selectionAdornmentTemplate =
        $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
            $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape, { stroke: "dodgerblue", strokeWidth: 2, fill: null }),
            $(go.Placeholder)
        ),
        $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
            { alignment: go.Spot.Top, alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Bottom },
            $("Button",
                { click: editText },  // defined below, to support editing the text of the node
                $(go.TextBlock, "t",
                { font: "bold 10pt sans-serif", desiredSize: new go.Size(15, 15), textAlign: "center" })
            ),
            $("Button",
            { // drawLink is defined below, to support interactively drawing new links
                click: drawLink,  // click on Button and then click on target node
                actionMove: drawLink  // drag from Button to the target node
            },
            $(go.Shape,
                { geometryString: "M0 0 L8 0 8 12 14 12 M12 10 L14 12 12 14" })
            ),
            $("Button",
            {
                actionMove: dragNewNode,  // defined below, to support dragging from the button
                _dragData: { text: "?????", color: "lightgray" },  // node data to copy
                click: clickNewNode  // defined below, to support a click on the button
            },
            $(go.Shape,
                { geometryString: "M0 0 L3 0 3 10 6 10 x F1 M6 6 L14 6 14 14 6 14z", fill: "gray" })
          )
        )
      );

    function editText(e, button) {
        //console.log(e);

      var node = button.part.adornedPart;
      console.log("node");
      //console.log(node);
      e.diagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK"));
      //$("#nodeText").val(node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK"));
    }

    function drawLink(e, button) {
      var node = button.part.adornedPart;
      var tool = e.diagram.toolManager.linkingTool;
      tool.startObject = node.port;
      e.diagram.currentTool = tool;
      tool.doActivate();
    }

   // used by both clickNewNode and dragNewNode to create a node and a link
    // from a given node to the new node
    function createNodeAndLink(data, fromnode) {
        var diagram = fromnode.diagram;
        var model = diagram.model;
        var nodedata = model.copyNodeData(data);
        model.addNodeData(nodedata);
        var newnode = diagram.findNodeForData(nodedata);
        var linkdata = model.copyLinkData({});
        model.setFromKeyForLinkData(linkdata, model.getKeyForNodeData(fromnode.data));
        model.setToKeyForLinkData(linkdata, model.getKeyForNodeData(newnode.data));
        model.addLinkData(linkdata);
        diagram.select(newnode);
        return newnode;
    }

    // the Button.click event handler, called when the user clicks the "N" button
    function clickNewNode(e, button) {
        var data = button._dragData;
        if (!data) return;
        e.diagram.startTransaction("Create Node and Link");
        var fromnode = button.part.adornedPart;
        var newnode = createNodeAndLink(button._dragData, fromnode);
        newnode.location = new go.Point(fromnode.location.x + 200, fromnode.location.y);
        e.diagram.commitTransaction("Create Node and Link");
    }

    // the Button.actionMove event handler, called when the user drags within the "N" button
    function dragNewNode(e, button) {
        var tool = e.diagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
        if (tool.isBeyondDragSize()) {
            var data = button._dragData;
            if (!data) return;
            e.diagram.startTransaction("button drag");  // see doDeactivate, below
            var newnode = createNodeAndLink(data, button.part.adornedPart);
            newnode.location = e.diagram.lastInput.documentPoint;
            // don't commitTransaction here, but in tool.doDeactivate, after drag operation finished
            // set tool.currentPart to a selected movable Part and then activate the DraggingTool
            tool.currentPart = newnode;
            e.diagram.currentTool = tool;
            tool.doActivate();
        }
    }

    // using dragNewNode also requires modifying the standard DraggingTool so that it
    // only calls commitTransaction when dragNewNode started a "button drag" transaction;
    // do this by overriding DraggingTool.doDeactivate:
    var tool = myDiagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
    tool.doDeactivate = function() {
        // commit "button drag" transaction, if it is ongoing; see dragNewNode, above
        if (tool.diagram.undoManager.nestedTransactionNames.elt(0) === "button drag") {
            tool.diagram.commitTransaction();
        }
        go.DraggingTool.prototype.doDeactivate.call(tool);  // call the base method
    };

    // replace the default Link template in the linkTemplateMap
    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
        $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        {
            curve: go.Link.Bezier, 
            adjusting: go.Link.Stretch,
            reshapable: true, 
            relinkableFrom: true, 
            relinkableTo: true,
            toShortLength: 3
        },
        new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
        new go.Binding("curviness"),
        $(go.Shape,  // the link shape
            { strokeWidth: 1.5 }),
        $(go.Shape,  // the arrowhead
            { toArrow: "standard", stroke: null }),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape,  // the label background, which becomes transparent around the edges
            {
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Radial",
                      { 0: "rgb(240, 240, 240)", 0.3: "rgb(240, 240, 240)", 1: "rgba(240, 240, 240, 0)" }),
                stroke: null
            }),
            $(go.TextBlock, "?????",  // the label text
            {
                textAlign: "center",
                font: "9pt helvetica, arial, sans-serif",
                margin: 4,
                editable: true  // enable in-place editing
            },
            // editing the text automatically updates the model data
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        )
    );


    var inspector = new Inspector('myInspectorDiv', myDiagram,
    {
        // uncomment this line to only inspect the named properties below instead of all properties on each object:
        // includesOwnProperties: false,
        properties: {
            "text": { },
            // an example of specifying the type
            "password": { show: Inspector.showIfPresent, type: 'password' },
            // key would be automatically added for nodes, but we want to declare it read-only also:
            "key": { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent },
            // color would be automatically added for nodes, but we want to declare it a color also:
            "color": { show: Inspector.showIfPresent, type: 'color' },
            // Comments and LinkComments are not in any node or link data (yet), so we add them here:
            "Comments": { show: Inspector.showIfNode  },
            "flag": { show: Inspector.showIfNode, type: 'checkbox' },
            "LinkComments": { show: Inspector.showIfLink },
            "isGroup": { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent }
        }
    });

    // read in the JSON data from flask
    loadGraphData();

    }

    function loadGraphData() {
        var graphDataString = JSON.parse('{{ diagramData | tojson | safe}}');
        console.log("graphDataString");
        console.log(graphDataString);

        myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(graphDataString);
    }

    function saveGraphData(form, event) {
        console.log("inside saveGraphData");
        event.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
        form.submit();
    }

    function zoomToFit(){
        console.log("inside zoomToFit");
        myDiagram.zoomToRect(myDiagram.documentBounds);
    }

    function zoomIn(){
        console.log("inside zoomIn");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.increaseZoom();
    }
    function zoomOut(){
        console.log("inside zoomOut");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.decreaseZoom();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

    <div id=formWrapper style="padding: 30px;">

        <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:5000/updateResultFile" name="updateResultFileForm" 
        id="updateResultFileForm" 
        onsubmit="saveGraphData(this, event);">

            <div id="graphWrapper" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100%; height: 800px;margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
                <div style="display: none;"><input id="mySavedModel" name="mySavedModel"></div>

                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"> Save <i class="fa fa-save"> </i> </button>

            </div>

        </form>

        <div id="myInspectorDiv">
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomToFit()"> Zoom to fit  <i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomIn()"> Zoom in  <i class="fa fa-search-plus"> </i> </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomOut()"> Zoom out  <i class="fa fa-search-minus"> </i> </button>
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that documentation page about user permissions, https://gojs.net/latest/intro/permissions.html, should give you an answer.

I'm guessing that you don't want to disable all deletions by setting **Diagram.allowDelete** to false, or to disable all in-place text editing by setting **Diagram.allowTextEdit** to false. Instead you probably want to prevent deleting or editing the original nodes and links but not any newly created nodes or links. Is that right?

If so, you can set or bind **Part.deletable** and **Part.textEditable** to false on all those original **Node**s and **Link**s. You can do that in an "InitialLayoutCompleted" DiagramEvent listener. For example in a Diagram initialization:

```
$(go.Diagram, . . .,
  { . . .,
    "InitialLayoutCompleted": function(e) {
        e.diagram.nodes.each(function(n) { n.deletable = false; n.textEditable = false; });
        e.diagram.links.each(function(l) { l.deletable = false; l.textEditable = false; });
      },
    . . .
 })
```

Of course you wouldn't need to set Link.textEditable to false if you didn't have any editable text labels in your Links, but you do seem to.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I needed :)